# Carriage return text resource in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, text, android-jetpack-compose

I have some text in a format like this...
Text1\nText2\nText3\nText4\nText5

and I want to convert it to a bulleted list in Jetpack Compose.  Any ideas?

Comment: How do you want your bulleted list to look in the end?

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val input = "Text1\nText2\nText3\nText4\nText5"
Text(text = "• $input".split("\n").joinToString("\n• "))
```

is probably the easiest option that produces this output:

[image]